# mySQL use row in table to find multiple rows in second table quickly

Tags: php, mysql

What would be the best way of obtaining data from a second table using a row from the first.

Imagine a website where a table in a database defines the individual pages. The pages are subsequently made out of multiple components. Components exist in another Table. For the page to select which components it needs, it has a column containing the ID numbers of the components its after eg.( 14,15,17,19

This would then be used in a mySQL query using IN(14,15,17,19) etc..

Is there a better approach than this?

Comment: You're looking for a JOIN, by the sounds of it.

Comment: This sounds like a straightforward join between related tables. Please post a sample of each of the input tables, together with a sample of what you intend the query output to be, given those input samples.

Comment: The column containing the id numbers is like "14,15,17,19", or are this values sotred in separate rows?<br>Is the relationship between these two tables 1:N, N:N ?

Comment: @TomasCeruti That was a column. We'd then run a query to get the corresponding rows from the components table.

Comment: As I undertsand, one page can have many components, but can a component belong to multiple pages? If so, this would be an N:N relationship and I would suggest creating an intermediate table that manages this relationship. With this you can do a simple join to get what you want

Comment: @TomasCeruti Yes some components could have multiple pages. Thanks

Comment: What actual problem are you solving? You gave us half the picture. What's slow and why do you think `IN()` is a bad choice? Performance + database problem is rarely solved only by altering query a bit.

Comment: It would be best to normalize your relation table, so each related ID is in a separate row, rather than a comma-separated list. But the duplicate question I linked to shows how to do it with a list.

Answer (score 1):

If the relationship is 1:N (each component can belong to only one page, but a page has multiple components), I would suggest to store the page_id in the components table. Then you can do a simple join between these two tables and you'll get the expected result.
If the relationship is N:N, I suggest creating an intermediate table "PagesComponents" that has the component_id and page_id. Then if yopu join the table Pages with PagesComponents with Components, you get the expected result.
If is not possible to modify the database, then I guess the IN(...) is probably the best option.